# How to pass a Variable in app.js to ./public/javascripts/myScript.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to pass a data set in `app.js` I got from MYSQL declared as `RESTAURANTS` to `./public/javascripts/myScript.js`

In `app.js`, I have this

```
connection.query('select * from restaurants limit 10', function (err, dataset, fields) {
        if (err) throw err; 
        RESTAURANTS = dataset;
    });
```

How can I use `RESTAURANTS` in `myScript.js`?

Comment: Can you provide some more information. For instance are you trying to pass RESTAURANTS from the server to the client and render on an html page? In which case you would need to do something else entirely. Perhaps some larger code snippets to explain what you are doing.

Comment: Yes! that's what I am trying to do -- passing RESTAURANTS from the server to the client and render on an html page (well jade page in this express folder).

Answer (score 0):

You can use module.exports and require like this:

In app.js at the end of the file

```
module.exports = RESTAURANTS;
```

And in ./public/javascripts/myScript.js at the top of the file

```
const RESTAURANTS = require('./app.js');
```

Note that the full path name has to be included in the string passed to require

```
'PATH_TO_FILE/app.js'
```

Replacing PATH_TO_FILE with the actual path.

Comment: It gives me an error that require is not define in myScript.js. I tried add require.js, but it didn't work probably because the layout of express folder works a bit differently.

Comment: require is a server side technology. If your running this on the client you should use webpack or browserify to serve your client files